# Laravel - Fail update model with many-to-many when using FormRequest validation

Tags: laravel, validation, many-to-many

I would need some help understanding what I am doing wrong.

I have really basic 'required' fields defined in a PostUpdateRequest rules method.

Then, my update method in PostController:

```
public function update(PostUpdateRequest $request, Post $post)
{
    $post->update($request->validated());
    $post->tags()->sync(request('tags'));
    return redirect() ...
}
```

When I use the method without validation, it works:

```
public function update(Request $request, Post $post)
{
    $post->update($request->all());
    $post->tags()->sync(request('tags'));
    return redirect() ...
}
```

I am not connecting the dots here ... I even have the store method that is working perfectly with FormValidation:

```
public function store(PostStoreRequest $request, Post $post)
{
    $post = Post::create($request->validated());
    $post->tags()->attach(request('tags'));
    return redirect() ...
}
```

My guess ... it's a validation thing ... the request never hits the controller action

Comment: please provide that form request ... and what is currently happening if it isn't hitting the controller?

Comment: Like @lagbox said, it's hard to see without your Request. My guess is that there's a required field missing from your PostUpdateRequest validation that's there when you just do a `$request->all()`. Try doing a `dd($request->validated());` in your first example and see if all the fields are there when you also do a `dd($request->all())` from your second example. If they really are interchangeable, then all the data in both requests should be there.

Comment: In the meantime I have figured it out ... It was my mistake when validating a field that didn't exist. Sorry for the trouble